# mysql - select query join in one table

Tags: mysql, date, join

I want to ask about how to join this queries?
The first i get from my table calendar when all Monday fetch out and the first in the month.

```
SELECT 
calender As Firsts
FROM
calender
WHERE
calender >= '2017-03-01'
    AND calender <= '2017-03-31'
    AND DAYOFWEEK(calender) = 2
    OR calender = '2017-03-01' 
GROUP BY calender;
```

And then I get from my table calendar to fetch out all Sunday and last day in the month.

```
SELECT 
calender As Lasted
FROM
calender
WHERE
calender.calender >= '2017-03-01'
    AND calender.calender <= '2017-03-31'
    AND DAYOFWEEK(calender) = 1
    OR calender = '2017-03-31'
GROUP BY calender;
```

And I want the output like this

```
First | Last
2017-03-01  | 2017-03-05
2017-03-06  | 2017-03-12
2017-03-13  | 2017-03-19
2017-03-20  | 2017-03-26
2017-03-27  | 2017-03-31
```

I've try used subquery then error 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row, is it possible to join this two queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is to assume you have primary key on your table `calendar`

```
SELECT 
   (SELECT calender 
    FROM calendar ic 
    WHERE ic.primary_key = oc.primary_key 
     AND DAYOFWEEK(ic.calender) = 2
    GROUP BY calendar) As First,
   (SELECT calender 
    FROM calendar ic 
    WHERE ic.primary_key = oc.primary_key 
     AND DAYOFWEEK(ic.calender) = 1
    GROUP BY calendar) As Last,
FROM 
  calender oc
WHERE
  calender >= '2017-03-01'
 AND calender <= '2017-03-31'
 OR calender = '2017-03-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be

```
SELECT ( SELECT calender FROM calender WHERE
    calender >= '2017-03-01'
        AND calender <= '2017-03-31'
        AND DAYOFWEEK(calender) = 2
        OR calender = '2017-03-01' 
        GROUP BY calender) As Firsts, ( SELECT calender FROM calender WHERE
    calender.calender >= '2017-03-01'
        AND calender.calender <= '2017-03-31'
        AND DAYOFWEEK(calender) = 1
        OR calender = '2017-03-31'
        GROUP BY calender
    ) As Last FROM calender
```

Comment: your query result is same, i think i got new way to get the result. I will answer my own question later, by the way thanks for your kindly help :D

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
startdate.Start, Enddate.End
FROM
(SELECT 
    @counter0:=@counter0 + 1 AS ID, calender AS Selesai
FROM
    calender, (SELECT @counter0:=0) T
WHERE
    calender BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
        AND DAYOFWEEK(calender) = 1
        OR calender = enddate) Enddate
    JOIN
(SELECT 
    @counter:=@counter + 1 AS ID, calender AS Mulai
FROM
    calender, (SELECT @counter:=0) T
WHERE
    calender BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
        AND DAYOFWEEK(calender) = 2
        OR calender = startdate) Startdate ON Startdate.ID = Enddate.ID
```

This is my way to solved my problem using row_number(), Thanks my best friend #Lun_Ng